# Celery Beat and doesn't work correctly With Django orm

Tags: django, celery, django-orm, celerybeat

I have configured celery and celery beat in Django and they are working correctly except for one problem,

When celery beat picks up my task and hand it to the celery worker, my query inside the task has no result, but when I check it myself it has results, below is my task:

```
@shared_task
def remove_expired_pending_task():
    call_command("remove_pending")
```

and below is the "**remove_pending**" command **handle** method:

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    try:
        aware = pytz.timezone("Asia/Tehran")

        min_date = aware.localize(jdatetime.datetime.now() - jdatetime.timedelta(hours=7))
        max_date = aware.localize(jdatetime.datetime.now() + jdatetime.timedelta(hours=7))
        q = Payment.objects.filter(
            is_completed=False,
            date__range=(min_date, max_date)
        )
        c = q.count()
        q.delete()

        self.stdout.write(
            f"{c} pending Payament deleted between\
                 {min_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H-%M-%S')} | \
                     {max_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H-%M-%S')}")
    except Exception as exc:
        self.stderr.write(
            f"Exception happend in 'Remove pendings'\n: {exc}")
```

and in the celery.py file after the celery **app** declaration I added this:

```
@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    
    sender.add_periodic_task(1000.0, remove_expired_pending_task.s(), name='remove_expired_pendings')
```

as I told, celery find and execute the task, but the query returns empty Queryset,
but when I run:

```
python manage.py remove_pending
```

EDIT
database configuration is:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": os.environ.get("SQL_ENGINE", "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2"),
        "NAME": os.environ.get("SQL_DATABASE", "something"),
        "USER": os.environ.get("SQL_USER", "something"),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("SQL_PASSWORD", "somethingpassword"),
        "HOST": os.environ.get("SQL_HOST", "localhost"),
        "PORT": os.environ.get("SQL_PORT", "5432"),
    }
```

It works and queryset is not empty and delete them successfully.
do you know why this happens?

Thank you.

Comment: What's your DB configuration?

Comment: @IainShelvington hi, I added the DB configuration in question.

Comment: Is it possible that your celery process has different environment variables and is connecting to a different DB?

Comment: @IainShelvington oh nice question, I'll check it and will inform you about the result. thanks

Comment: @IainShelvington thank you, sir, that was it, celery object was created with development settings so it uses sqlite3 development database, but Django uses production settings and Postgres. thanks again